# how do i make my screen into 4 equal div's that expand when you hover on them?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

so the title sort of explains it but i mocked up some images in ms paint for reference.
when it launches the web page looks sort of like this:
[image]

when you hover over the top left the top left square expands and the other three shrink:
[image]

or when you hover over the bottom right:

[image]

I have tried it with jquery and CSS, jquery works to an extent but while the divs are transitioning they all stack up underneath eachother.

this is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="screenfiller">
    <div id="1">

    </div>
    <div id="2">

    </div>
    <div id="3">

    </div>
    <div id="4">

    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
#screenfiller {
position: absolute;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}

#1{
width: 50%;
float: left;
position: static;
background-size:     cover;                      /* <------ */
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
display: flex;
}

#2{
width: 50%;
background-color: yellow;
float: left;
position: static;
background-size:     cover;                      /* <------ */
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
display: flex;
}

#3{
width: 50%;
background-color: red;
float: left;
position: static;
background-size:     cover;                      /* <------ */
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
display: flex;
}

#4{
width: 50%;
background-color: green;
float: left;
position: static;
background-size:     cover;                      /* <------ */
background-repeat:   no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
display: flex;
}
```

my JQuery:

```
$('#1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#tech').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#qual').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#work').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#pers').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
});
$('#2').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#work').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#pers').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#tech').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#qual').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
});
$('#3').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#qual').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#tech').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#pers').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#work').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
});
$('#4').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#pers').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#work').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#qual').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#tech').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
});
```

**EDIT:**

heres what i want it to actually look like live:

web page at launch:

[image]

when hovering over top left square:

[image]

When hovering over bottom right square:

[image]

Comment: your jquery doesn't work. the elements you're referencing don't exist. and [id's can't start with a number](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
$('#a1').hover(function(){
    $('#a1').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#a2').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#a3').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#a4').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
});
$('#a2').hover(function(){
    $('#a1').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#a2').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#a3').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#a4').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
});
$('#a3').hover(function(){
    $('#a1').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#a2').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#a3').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#a4').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
});
$('#a4').hover(function(){
    $('#a1').animate({ height: "45%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#a2').animate({ height: "45%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
    $('#a3').animate({ height: "55%", width: "45%"}, 500 );
    $('#a4').animate({ height: "55%", width: "55%"}, 500 );
});
```

```css
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin:0;
}
#screenfiller {
position: relative;
top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

#a1{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#a2{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#a3{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#a4{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="screenfiller">
    <div id="a1">

    </div>
    <div id="a2">

    </div>
    <div id="a3">

    </div>
    <div id="a4">

    </div>    
</div>
```

You can adjust it to your needs.